# indoor positioning system with redpin

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system, redpin

I try to design basic indoor project to understand red pin. After this I designed my campus.

I want to do this; [basic example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFSmu4orH1Q)

I download this project; [Project](https://github.com/kelvinyap92/CS4900_Redpin)

How can I import my map on this project. And Why this error. How can I work this code

but it is give this eror

```
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.redpin.android.net.Request$5
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.Request.setTypes(Request.java:188)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.Request.<init>(Request.java:83)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.Request.<init>(Request.java:71)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.home.RemoteEntityHome.performRequest(RemoteEntityHome.java:112)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.home.RemoteEntityHome.performRequest(RemoteEntityHome.java:66)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.home.MapRemoteHome.getMapList(MapRemoteHome.java:62)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.SynchronizationManager.sync(SynchronizationManager.java:142)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at org.redpin.android.net.SynchronizationManager.onCreate(SynchronizationManager.java:59)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2433)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:146)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
03-03 16:06:05.388: E/AndroidRuntime(5608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 16:06:05.411: D/dalvikvm(5608): GC_CONCURRENT freed 275K, 18% free 7754K/9415K, paused 14ms+3ms, total 38ms
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that those classes are not in your classpath.